# Trim leading white space with PHP?

Tags: php, whitespace, trim

There seems to be a bug in a Wordpress PHP function that leaves whitespace in front of the title of the page generated by `<?php echo wp_title(''); ?>`  I've been through the Wordpress docs and forums on that function without any luck.

I'm using it this way `<body id="<?php echo wp_title(''); ?>">` in order to generate an HTML body tag with the id of the page title.

So what I need to do is strip that white space, so that the body tag looks like this `<body id="mypage">`  instead of this `<body id="  mypage">`

The extra white space kills the CSS I'm trying to use to highlight menu items of the active page. When I manually add a correct body tag without the white space, my CSS works.

So how would I strip the white space?  Thanks, Mark

---

Part Two of the Epic

John, A hex dump was a good idea; it shows the white space as two "20" spaces. But all solutions that strip leading spaces and white space didn't.

And,  `<?php ob_start(); $title = wp_title(''); ob_end_clean(); echo $title; ?>`

gives me `< body id ="">`

and `<?php ob_start(); $title = wp_title(''); echo $title; ?>`

gives me `< body id ="  mypage">`

Puzzle. The root of the problem is that wp_title has optional page title leading characters - that look like chevrons - that are supposed to be dropped when the option is false, and they are, but white space gets dumped in.

Is there a nuclear option?

---

Yup, tried them both before; they still return two leading spaces...  arrgg

Answer (score 38, accepted):

1. Strip all whitespace from the left end of the title:

   ```
   <?php echo ltrim(wp_title('')); ?>
   ```
2. Strip all whitespace from either end:

   ```
   <?php echo trim(wp_title('')); ?>
   ```
3. Strip all spaces from the left end of the title:

   ```
   <?php echo ltrim(wp_title(''), ' '); ?>
   ```
4. Remove the first space, even if it's not the first character:

   ```
   <?php echo str_replace(' ', '', wp_title(''), 1); ?>
   ```
5. Strip only a single space (not newline, not tab) at the beginning:

   ```
   <?php echo preg_replace('/^ /', '', wp_title('')); ?>
   ```
6. Strip the first character, whatever it is:

   ```
   <?php echo substr(wp_title(''), 1); ?>
   ```

## Update

From the Wordpress [documentation on `wp_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_title), it appears that `wp_title` displays the title itself unless you pass `false` for the second parameter, in which case it returns it. So try:

```
<?php echo trim(wp_title('', false)); ?>
```

Comment: You definately get the prize for scope and variety, and they all should work. But something is wacky with the Wordpress function and I still have whitespace. Firebug shows it as whitespace, not any sort of character....

Comment: Part Two of the Epic is tacked onto my original question!

Comment: Why not use PHP to convert the resulting string to HEX and see what character code is being used at the beginning?  Or you could always just take a substr() and clip off the first character.

Comment: That picture made me laugh waaay more than it should have. I was just expecting a technical response and ran into it and it caught me totally off-guard.

Comment: lool. someone deserves a medal.

Comment: `<body id="<?php trim(wp_title('', false)); ?>">`  returns 

`<body id="">`

And `<?php echo substr(wp_title(''), 1); ?>`  won't trim the leading spcaes, either...

Very strange. But John deserves 1000 points for all this...

Comment: I might need 2000 if I have to go install Wordpress to answer this question!

Comment: Wait, you're mixing those up. You need to pass false AND do an echo. Try `<?php echo trim(wp_title('', false)); ?>`.

Comment: Jeez. How did I screw that up? Not fully understanding the docs and not watching what I was doing here. And up too late and half asleep this morning, too. This works fine:

`<body id="<?php echo trim(wp_title('', false)); ?>">`

Really appreciate it. You deserve a all expenses paid vacation at the Bat Cave, with unlimited miles on the Batmobile....

Comment: The leading spaces in wp_title the Wordpress function appear to be a bug that isn't going be fixed as it will break many themes, according to their bug tracking system. I posted John's resolution in the Wordpress forums...

Answer (score 10):

[`ltrim()`](http://www.php.net/ltrim)

Answer (score 1):

```
ltrim($str)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to throw in some variety here: [trim](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

```
 <body id="<?=trim(wp_title('', false));?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this info!  I was in the same boat in that I needed to generate page ids for CSS purposes based on the page title and the above solution worked beautifully.

I ended up having an additional hurdle in that some pages have titles with embedded spaces, so I ended up coding this:

```
<?php echo str_replace(' ','-',trim(wp_title('',false))); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your functions.php

```
add_filter('wp_title', create_function('$a, $b','return str_replace(" $b ","",$a);'), 10, 2);
```

should work like a charm