# Removing all space in string before the first non space character

Tags: php, string

The title says it all. I need to remove any existing space before reaching the first non space character.

For example, consider `"        Hello World"` a string that we want to operate on.
I need to convert it to `"Hello World"`. How would I do that in PHP?

Comment: You can use [trim](http://php.net/trim) for removing spaces from both sides of a string. Or [ltrim](http://php.net/ltrim) for removing only from the left side.

Comment: Use [`ltrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) function.

Comment: @Andrew, Rajdeep, if you provide that as answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101322/trim-leading-white-space-with-php, is a better duplicate, the matched duplicate is for any whitespace, not specific to leading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ltrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) function to remove whitespaces from the beginning of a string.

```
$str = "        Hello World";
$sanitized_string = ltrim($str);
echo $sanitized_string;  // Hello World
```