# How can I trim/remove spaces from the end of a string in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a string like "Tom Jerry ". I want to trim the extra space from the end of the string. I.e. desirable output is "Tom Jerry". How do I do that?

Comment: just  use `trim( "Tom Jerry ")`  function is used to remove the white spaces

Comment: You need to use `trim()`

Comment: possible duplicated :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101322/trim-leading-white-space-with-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trim leading white space with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101322/trim-leading-white-space-with-php)

Answer (score 6):

There is a `trim` method in php: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

```
trim("Tom Jerry ");
```

Answer (score 4):

use the trim(string) function ??

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_trim.asp

Comment: Would be better if you pointed to the official PHP Docs rather than a 3rd party site

Answer (score 4):

You should use rtrim instead. It will remove extra white space at the end of a string and is faster than using preg_replace.

```
$str = "This is a string.    ";
echo rtrim($str);
```

source : [Remove extra space at the end of string using preg_replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787219/remove-extra-space-at-the-end-of-string-using-preg-replace?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 2):

you can use `trim()`

```php
<?php
    $str = "tom jerry ";
    echo "Without trim: " . $str;
    echo "\n";
    echo "With trim: " . trim($str);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to use [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

```
echo trim(' tom jerry   ');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    trim("Tom Jerry ");
?>
```

more [example](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_trim.asp) from w3schools

Answer (score 1):

for a string `$string = " my name is Stark ";`
use `ltrim($string)` to trim whitespace from the beginning of the string, use `rtrim($string)` to trim whitespace from the end of the string, use `trim($string)` to remove whitespace from both ends. you can also add an extra parameter (a character mask) if you want to specifically remove another character also, apart from whitespace from the end or beginning of a string e.g trailing slashes(`" onefunnyurl.com/"`)