# Just a space for words and remove if you only have one space

Tags: php, regex

I currently have this regex to leave only one space per words

```
preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $string);
```

However, he is leaving a space at the beginning and if the user types only spaces, that space also appears

```
$string = "  test string   test";
echo preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $string);
```

Result: " test string test"

I want this result: 
Result: "test string test"

Comment: You can trim the string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trim leading white space with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101322/trim-leading-white-space-with-php)

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yes, thanks, I solved my problem with the trim()